# How can i delete the value of a column in powerbuilder?

Tags: buffer, reset, powerbuilder

I have a datawindow with 3 selection criteria. This selection criteria are 3 columns. If the user writes something in one of them, than he can't use the others. If he tries to do that a message aware the user that he can use only one criteria. The problem is that after he deletes or cuts what he wrote before and he tries to write something in another column, the message still pop-up. I think that the buffer still contain the last value. How can i reset it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have to nullify the 'deleted' column.  I would do it that way: in the 'ItemChanged', post:

```
if dwo.name = 'yourcolumn' and data = '' then
   SetNull(ls_null)
   post dw_selection.Setitem(row, dwo.name, ls_null)
end if
```

This, of course, needs to be adapted to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "itemchanged" event of the datawindow with the returned values:

Return value

Set the return code to affect the outcome of the event:

0  (Default) Accept the data value

1 Reject the data value and do not allow focus to change

2  Reject the data value but allow the focus to change